# How to generate traffic alert in android by using GPS?

Tags: android, geolocation

How to generate traffic alert in android when user is in travel?

By using GPS I can get user location, and I have to generate automatic traffic alert, this alert is only for those who are in travel not for others. So how do i get user is in travel or not?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean user is moving or not ?

Comment: This alert have to appear when user moving from one place to another place. This is only for those who are in travel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only suppose that the user is travelling by checking if and how fast she is moving. You get the speed along with the current position in the `Location` object. Probably you'll compute some average speed over a certain amount of time, e.g. 10 seconds or a minute to make sure.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is it possible to identify that user is on road by using GPS?

Comment: No, GPS just gives you the position - latitude and longitude. You'd have to check if there is a road at that position by other mean, but I don't know how and I'm afraid that's not that simple.